# setInterval() and setTimeout() do nothing on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, settimeout, setinterval

My Node.js app works as intended and runs without errors on VSCode. However, setInterval() and setTimeout() do nothing once my app runs on heroku. I knew this because I wrote console.log() everywhere and looked at the heroku log of my app. None of the console.log() statements inside a setInterval() or setTimeout() were executed.

Surprisingly, all other functions of this app worked on heroku.

Here is the segment of code.

```js
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
    config = require("./config.json");
    // console.log("index line 44: entered loop");
    if (config["reminder#" + fixedCount] == undefined) return clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    config["reminder#" + fixedCount]["time"] -= 5 * 60 * 1000;
    if (config["reminder#" + fixedCount]["time"] > 0) updateJson();
}, (5 * 60 * 1000));

setTimeout(() => {
    const color = "#" + hexCodes[~~(Math.random() * hexCodes.length)], userID = config["reminder#" + fixedCount]["user"];
    const userObject = client.users.cache.get(userID);
    let sendReminder = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Reminder to ${userObject.username.split("#")[0]}`)
        .setColor(color)
        .setDescription(config["reminder#" + fixedCount]["content"]);
    userObject.send({embeds: [sendReminder]}).catch(err => { });
    delete config["reminder#" + fixedCount];
    updateJson();
}, config["reminder#" + fixedCount]["time"]);
```

Any idea why this happened?

Comment: It's next to impossible to help you without seeing the offending code.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question @LucaKiebel! I edited my question. Please let me know if you have questions :)

Comment: Note that `config = require("./config.json");` will always give you the same data, even if you change `config.json` on disk, because Node's `require()` mechanism caches dependencies (for obvious reasons). Really: the fact that this does something on _your_ machine is the curious part. If you want to read in a file that changes over time, don't use `require`, instead load it in using `fs` and if it happens to be a JSON file, run it through `JSON.parse`. And then of course remember that files can get completely mangled, so you'll have to try/catch a few possible failure states.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I will try it right now :)

Comment: Thanks Mike! setTimeout() and setInterval() now work on my heroku app. I read the config file using `config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json'));`. You also reminded me that writing to and loading files can take some time, so I used setTimeout() in some places to adjust to that.